# How to Register and Resolve conditionally Generic type Using Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

My main Model Classes are "RoleMaster and "UserMaster"

```
public  class RoleMaster
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public  class UserMaster
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is My main Repository Interface

```
   public interface IRepository<in T> where T : class 
   {
       bool Add(T entity);
   }
```

Implemented Class for RoleMaster

```
public class RoleRepository : IRepository<RoleMaster>
    {

        public bool Add(RoleMaster entity)
        {
             //Add Logic
        }
}
```

Implemented Class for UserMaster

```
  public class UserRepository : IRepository<UserMaster>
        {
            public bool Add(UserMaster entity)
            {
              //Add Logic
            }
    }
```

Now i want to achieve

```
 container.RegisterType<(IRepository<T>)(new InjectionFactory(m =>
            {
                if (typeof(T) is RoleMaster)
                {
                    m.Resolve<RoleRepository>();
                }
                else if (typeof(T) is UserMaster)
                {
                    m.Resolve<UserRepository>();
                }
                return m;
            }));
```

Is it possible using Unity?

What is the best way to do this kind of conditional Resolve?

Comment: When you find yourself checking against types in a generic class/method your design has failed somewhere along the way.

Comment: Then what is best way to do this kind of operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just register them explicitly with unity

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<RoleMaster>, RoleRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IRepository<UserMaster>, UserRepository>();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you go with either the generic repository pattern or create a new interface for every repository.  Or a combination of the two, but that can get confusing.

With generic repository (there are plenty of examples out there), you would only make one call to the container to register the open generics types as there is only one implementation of the `IRepsitory<T>` interface...

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

But if you plan to add custom methods on each repository, you will likely need those methods defined on a custom repository interface for that entity type.  Then registration would best be done on the custom repository interface instead of the generic interface...

```
container.RegisterType<IRepositoryRole, RoleRepository>();

public interface IRepositoryRole : IRepository<RoleMaster> 
{
    public void DoCustomRoleWork(...) { ... }
}
```